# Laravel Email attachment error (Expected response code 250 but got code "421", with message "421 4.4.2)

Tags: php, laravel, email

**Swift_TransportException**

***Expected response code 250 but got code "421", with message "421 4.4.2 Message submission rate for this client has exceeded the configured limit "***

File attached: 6mb

```
 $data=[
      'id'=>$id,
      'dokument'=>$dokument,
      'extension'=>$extension,
  ];

   Mail::to('email@email.com')->send(new \App\Mail\Mail($data));

       $documentRequest=$this->data['dokument'];
        $id=$this->data['id'];

        if(!empty($documentRequest)  ){
            return $this->subject('test')
            ->view('Mail.view',compact('id'))
            ->attach(public_path('/dokumenta/form/'.$this->data['dokument']), [
                'as' => 'Document.'.$this->data['extension'],
                'mime' => 'application/'.$this->data['extension'],
            ]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very common to receive 421 errors these days. They are used by receivers to control delivery speed if they think you are spamming. According to RFC821, 421 means "Service unavailable", but it's frequently used to say "I'm busy now, come back later", and the sending server is expected to do just that - put the message back in its queue and retry again later.

Obviously when you're sending directly through a remote service, you probably didn't want to have to do all that tedious queue and retry handling, and indeed, a Laravel app is not the place to implement that.

The right way to fix this is to configure a local mail server to relay through a remote service, then get your script to submit to that. This way your app will be much more responsive (submitting to localhost is essentially instant), and the mail server will deal with queuing and retries. Postfix works very well for this.

Comment: +Synchro Thank you for your reply, by editing my mail.php in the config files and setting manually my local_domain  will it fix the problem
'local_domain' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mail.mydomain.com'),